# How to send upstream FCM notification from android to spring boot server using XMPP protocol?

Tags: android, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp

I am working on a spring-boot project. Where I am sending FCM notification from my server to android application using Firebase using HTTP protocol, but there is one major update Send FCM notification using XMPP protocol. Using this protocol I am sending Downstream FCM notification(Server to Android applications) but I am getting issues for sending Upstream FCM notification (Android application to Server)

Following URL is used for reference

https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-integration/firebase-cloud-messaging-xmpp-server-example-receive-upstream-messages-spring-integration